# Ankiのアドオンを実行できません。助けてください

Tags: python, json

#### 解決したいこと

ankiのカードの評価と評価した時刻をcsvファイルにまとめて出力するアドオンを作成しました。
これを実行したいのですが、以下のようなエラーが出ています。
anki-review_resultsフォルダに、空の__init__.py、Anki_rating_time_record.py、manifest.jsonというファイルを格納し、圧縮後に拡張子を.ankiaddonに変換しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
anki-review-results.ankiaddon⁩ のインストール中にエラーが発生しました: 
⁨無効なアドオンのマニフェスト⁩
当該アドオン作成者に報告してください
```

#### 自分で試したこと

Ankiのバージョンを最新のものに変更した。
manifest.jsonのインデントを変更した。

#### ソースコード

Anki_rating_time_record.py

```
import anki_python_api
import csv
import datetime

# reset anki api
anki = anki_python_api.Anki()

review_results = []

def review_did_answer_card(result, card, ease):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    review_results.append((result, card, ease, now))
    
# register Anki API
anki.add_review_did_answer_card_callback(review_did_answer_card)

# start anki
anki.run()

# save the results on csv format
with open("review_results.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["timestamp", "result","card","ease"])
    for all_result in review_results:
        writer.writerow([all_result[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),all_result[1],
                         all_result[2],all_result[3]])
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name" : "Anki-review-results",
    "package":"ankiaddon.ankiaddon"
   
}
```

Comment: 幾つもマルチポストしているようですが、そうした他にも質問記事があることを明記して、助言・回答が得られたり内容を更新した場合は全てを同期して更新するようにしてください。[Ankiのアドオンを作成できません...](https://qiita.com/kouzunomori2021/questions/99232aad67ab27356024), [Issue with exporting anki card rating and time on csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75492324/9014308), [Issue with exporting on csv](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/issue-with-exporting-on-csv/27578)

Comment: 承知しました。
他にQiitaとAnki Forumにて同様の質問記事を投稿しています。
Anki forumで、manifest.jsonでのkey指定を見直すべしと指摘を受けました。
その後、必須とされるname, packageのみを指定して再試行しましたが同じ状況です。
packageが実行アドオンのフォルダと同名であることは確認済みです。

本投稿に、以上を反映させておきます。

Comment: `anki-review-results`というのは貴方の作成しているモジュールだと思われますが、提示されたソースコードの最初にimportしている`anki_python_api`というのは`PyPI`や`GitHub`で検索しても出てこないようです。それも独自のローカルなモジュールでしょうか？ それに関する情報や、あるいは既存のAddonのソースとかAddonの作り方のサンプル/Tutorialといった情報はあるのでしょうか？ そうしたものから違いを調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
上記の通りに変更しましたが、エラーの状況は変わっておりません。
助言いただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 情報の追加はコメントではなく質問記事を編集して行ってください。おそらくこんなサイトや記事 [Awesome Anki](https://github.com/tianshanghong/awesome-anki),[anki-addons-misc](https://github.com/glutanimate/anki-addons-misc),[anki-addon](https://github.com/topics/anki-addon) が関連するものと思われますが、これらのどれかに類似のものがあればそれが参考になるのでは？ それから古そうですがこんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Anki のアドオンを書く](https://t-cool.github.io/anki-addon-docs-ja/intro.html), [Anki 2.1.x アドオンの作成 日本語訳](https://rs.luminousspice.com/ankiaddons21/)